# Reversing the layout of a QToolButton

Tags: qt

I would like to make a `QToolButton` where the text is the left of its icon.  I've tried to find related information, and tried things with:

```
button->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon);
```

but this sets the text to the right side of the button.  I've looked into trying stylesheets, but text-alignment is only for push buttons.  Is there any way to do this?

My highest-level goal is to make an interface bar which looks like this:

[image: goal]

with a text label and image right beside it.  Currently I'm using a toolbar with checkable toolbuttons because of the style (no border unless moused-over, still has the indent with checkable, contains text and an icon...).  It's entirely possible that I'm using the wrong type widgets, so if I can't change the layout of this, is there any way to emulate this style?

This is what I currently have:

[image: current].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `QWidget::setLayoutDirection`:

```
toolbar->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to create this functionality yourself in a QWidget. It should have a QLabel and a QToolButton (or QPushButton) arranged in a QHBoxLayout. Then you can add this custom widget to the toolbar using `QToolBar::addWidget()` or `QToolBar::insertWidget()`.

Here's an example of a widget you could use:

```
#include <QtGui>

class CoolButton : public QWidget
{
public:
    CoolButton(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hi!", this);
        QToolButton *button = new QToolButton(this);
        QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
        layout->addWidget(label);
        layout->addWidget(button);
        setLayout(layout);
    }
};
```